# MySQL JOIN and COUNT failure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I have 2 tables in a MySQL database.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|student:    |name      |neptunid |signature |sex  |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|signature:  |studentid |classid  |start     |end  |startsig  |endsig
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have to search for a given `classid` and get back with following information:

- name of the student (studentid=neptunid)
- signature from table student
- startsig field is also necessary
- sum of students per sex

I have tried with the following query,  but don't know, how to define, that sex field should be counted (male/female).

```
SELECT st.name,st.neptunid,st.signature,si.startsig
FROM student st JOIN signature si ON st.neptunid=si.studentid
WHERE si.start<'$today' AND si.end>'$today'
```

Comment: `sum of students per sex` ... it isn't clear how this should be worked into your result set.  Can you show us sample output (and, ideally, input too) ?

Comment: Looks like you need *conditional aggregation*:`count(case when sex = 'M' then sex end as sex_male)`, this returns NULL for `F` which is not counted. Similar for female.

Comment: @dnoeth : Could you please put this clause into query? I am not sure, where to use this.

Comment: `$today` variable contains current date in `d/m/Y H:i:s format`.

Comment: At a second look it's not a COUNT(CASE), but a Scalar Subquery:`SELECT st.name,st.neptunid,st.signature,si.startsig, (select count(*) from student st2 where st.sex = st2.sex) 
FROM student st JOIN signature si ON st.neptunid=si.studentid
WHERE si.start<'$today' AND si.end>'$today'

Comment: @dnoeth : I have tried also with some modifications, but this cannot count person per gender. It can say for example 3, but don't groupped by gender.